# getting object instead of array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have string data[2] which in test is "6766 44 9 19904 7772 13323 245 14 221" and trying to convert it to array using code below

```
console.log(typeof(data[2]),data[2].length,data[2]);
con = data[2].trim().split("\\s+"); // i.e. 66 44 9 19904 7772 13323 245 14 221
console.log(typeof(con),con.length,con);
```

But getting below object instead, please advice

```
string 38  6766 44 9 19904 7772 13323 245 14 221
object 1 ["6766 44 9 19904 7772 13323 245 14 221"]
```

Comment: Arrays are objects in JS, and `typeof` returns "object" when testing an array. As you can see, you have an array.

Comment: And use Array.isArray(con) to test for an array. Arrays are objects in JS.

Comment: Also `typeof` is... special.

Comment: @FelixKling, it seems you've misspelled "useless"...FTFY.

Comment: @zzzzBov: It's still good for testing for functions ;)

Comment: @zzzzBov How would you check if a variable is defined without throwing a reference error if you don't use `typeof foo !== 'undefined'` ?

Comment: @Shashank the remark was meant to be tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is incorrect because you split by a string but could be a regexp:

```
con = data[2].trim().split("\\s+");
```

Could be

```
con = data[2].trim().split(/\s+/);
```

Comment: "could be" no "should be"

Answer (score 9):

You're trying to use a string to split instead of a regex:

change `.split("\\s+")` to `.split(/\s+/g)`.

The `typeof` operation will return `"object"` for arrays, so you're actually seeing an array with a single item, which is why your count is wrong.

If you want to check if an object is an array, use `Array.isArray`, or for compatibility:

```
function isArray(arr) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) === '[object Array]';
}
```

Comment: Is the `g` flag necessary here?

Comment: @axelduch, probably not, but I recall some methods only match the first instance, and this appears to be a case where splitting should happen on all spaces, so the `g` flag makes sense to me. I honestly hadn't tested it.

Comment: Split is implicitly global already, but it is true for methods like `String.prototype.replace`